# Measuring an electromagnet

Tags: power, electromagnetism, magnet

I'm working on a project. I'm going to use a 'pulsing' electromagnet, and want to know how much power it's draining.

Is it just a case of, if I'm using a 12 V battery for example, then I'm using 12 V? Or is there a way to hook it up to a volt meter or DMM?

Also, does the magnet get stronger simply by coiling the wire more times around the iron core? Or are there other variables?

Answer (score 2):

Electrical power is calculated by multiplying volts by amps. The answer is in watts.

$$ P = V\cdot I $$

Ohm's Law says that \$ V = I\cdot R \$ so we can derive two other ways of calculating the power:

$$ P = V\cdot I = I\cdot R\cdot I = I^2\cdot R $$

or

$$ P = V\cdot I = V\cdot\frac {V}{R} = \frac {V^2}{R} $$

---

To calculate power you need to take two measurements.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdUv9K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Current and voltage measurement.*

- Measure the current by connecting your meter in series with the load.
- Measure the voltage across the load.

Be very careful to connect the meter leads to the right sockets and select the correct range before switching on power.

Comment: If no better answer comes along within a day or so then please accept this answer.

Comment: Sorry im new to this, how do I accept the answer?

Comment: There should be a checkmark symbol underneath the vote up/down arrows. As I say, wait a while!

Answer (score 1):

Let me address the second of your questions: Is the magnetic field stronger if you add more turns to the coil?

It depends.

Generally, if you push the same current through two coils, the one with more turns will generate the stronger field. However, the coil with more turns also has a higher electrical resistance (longer wire...) so you need a higher voltage to achieve the same current.

In your case, you are using a battery to drive the coil, so the voltage is given. In this case, both effects will (to some extent!) cancel out. The more turns you wind, the lower the current flowing (and the less heat will be generated), but the field strength is not affected a lot.

However, a coil with many turns also has a high inductance. Think of the inductance as a sort of inertia, which opposes any current changes in the coil. A high inductance will limit the ability to send a short pulse through the coil. Also, when opening the circuit (switching the magnet off), the coil will generate a high voltage, possible generating a spark arcing the switching contacts.

So you'll have to experiment to find the optimal configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic field strength is proportional to Amperes * Turns

The volts for a certain currrent depends on the coil resistance, which depends on the wire diameter, the number of turns and the mean winding length per turn.

If the current is too high for the coil resistance the coil will overheat.

Now, here is something you may find useful:

For a given physical arrangement of coil (fixed core and winding 'window') the field strength, when optimally designed, is roughly the same for a the same input power (in watts) regardless of the voltage.

In other words (for given physical dimensions), an optimal 10V 1A solenoid generates about as strong a magnetic  field as the same solenoid wound for  100V 100mA. The higher voltage coil will have many more turns of finer wire. At really low and high voltages this relationship tends to break down, but for say 5V to 50V it works well.

---

To see this: The magnetic field strength \$M \propto I \cdot n \$ where I is the current and n is the number of turns.

The coil power \$P = I \cdot V\$ is constant for a given arrangement so the coil resistance \$ R \propto V^2\$

\$ n \propto 1/a\$ where a is the cross-sectional area of the wire (for a fixed window area fill)

The coil resistance \$ R \propto n/a\$

So \$ R \propto n^2 \text{ and thus } n \propto V\$

So the field strength \$M \propto \frac {V\cdot n}{R}\$  is approximately constant regardless of the design voltage V for an optimal coil (defined here as when the window is filled with copper wire to the largest extent practical).

---

If you can figure out roughly how many watts your coil can dissipate (it will also depend on the insulation class of the wire, and whether the solenoid needs to be rated for continuous duty or if momentary is okay) you can then calculate the total resistance of the wire. From the window area (with some allowances because you can't fill it 100%) you can figure the gauge of wire that will give you the appropriate resistance and fill the window almost fully. The number of turns follows from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the amount of current drawn using an ammeter or multimeter. You just have to add a shunt resistor in parallel to the ammeter. The value of the required shunt can be calculated by:

Ig G =Is S

where:

Ig = Amount of current that your ammeter can handle; usually it's 10 A but consider 5 A for safety.

G = Resistance of your ammeter. You need another multimeter to calculate resistance.

Is = It - Ig (where It is the total current that you expect to flow. You can keep the value 2-3 times the orignal value.

Is = The value of the shunt that you require.